# Equivalent Raw data type of Oracle in Hive

Tags: oracle, hive

I have a table in Oracle DB with RAW data type.

```
 CREATE TABLE rawdata
 (
    c1 RAW(11)
 );
```

Can I create table in Hive with similar kind of data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `binary` datatype of hive

Answer (score 0):

### The below can be usefull.

ref :https://help.sap.com/viewer/3193f0548ba14c999b0275b5e9013760/16.0.3.3/en-US/69032bce8a5f4595915112964747ff94.html

```
Oracle datatype        Replication Definition datatype      Hive datatype
Integer                          rs_oracle_decimal             double
Number                           rs_oracle_decimal             double
Number(10) - Number(18)          rs_oracle_decimal             Bigint
Number(5) - Number(9)            rs_oracle_decimal             int
Number(2) - Number(4)            rs_oracle_decimal             smallint
Number(P,S)                      rs_oracle_decimal/varchar     decimal/varchar
Number(1)                        rs_oracle_decimal             tinyint
FLOAT                            rs_oracle_float               double
BINARY_FLOAT                     rs_oracle_float               double
BINARY_DOUBLE                    rs_oracle_decimal             double
DATE                             rs_oracle_datetime            timestamp
TIMESTAMP(N)                     rs_oracle_timestamp9          timestamp
CHAR                             Char                          varchar
NCHAR                            Unichar                       varchar
VARCHAR2                         Varchar                       varchar
NVARCHAR                         univarchar                    varchar
NVARCHAR2                        univarchar                    varchar
BLOB                             image                         No Default
BFILE                            image                         No Default
NCLOB                            unitext                       No Default
INTERVAL                         rs_oracle_interval            No Default
ROWID                            rs_oracle_rowid               No Default
UROWID                           rs_oracle_rowid               No Default
TIMESTAMP with time zone         rs_oracle_timestamptz         No Default
TIMESTAMP with local time zone   rs_oracle_timestamp9          No Default
ANYDATA                          opaque                        No Default
VARRAY                           opaque                        No Default
NESTEDTAB                        opaque                        No Default
Object                           opaque                        No Default
REF                              rs_oracle_binary              No default
RAW                              rs_oracle_binary              binary
```